# AspectC++ in ROS?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Does anyone have any experience using AspectC++ in ROS? Does ROS provide support in a way similar to other third party tools, such as Qt?

Thanks for the insight.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31930/aspectc++-in-ros?/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not familiar with AspectC++ and haven't heard of it being used with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0